# Open link from uiwebview into new view

Tags: view, uiwebview

I am creating an app that uses UIWebViews and was wondering if it is possible to open a link that the user clicks in the original webview in a different view?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `UIWebView` do that automatically for you, but here's a rough outline of what to implement if you need one:

1. Intercept the link in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` and keep it somewhere.
2. Do a `return NO;` to prevent the link from loading inline.
3. Open the new view (if it doesn't already exist).
4. Inject the link from (1) in the `UIWebView` inside the other view using `loadRequest:`